# Regex, filter only numbers

Tags: java, regex, graph

I am beginner in Java so currently I am learning about regex and i want to filter only numbers from file txt. I need to add edges to graph but first i want to filter my numbers.

File .txt

```
1 2
1;3 5 4 3        4 
1       
7
4@2
5   6 1
6.8
9 10m
```

My code:

```
public class Main {

    private static final String filename = "/Users/user/Desktop/exercises/files/test.txt";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename))) {

            String line = br.readLine();

            while(line!= null) {
                String[] edge = line.trim().split("\\s+");

                for(int i = 0; i < edge.length; i+=2) {
                    int v = Integer.parseInt(edge[i]);
                    int u = Integer.parseInt(edge[i] + 1);
                    System.out.println(v + ", " + u);
                }
                line = br.readLine();
            }


        }catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("File does not exist!!");
        }

    }

}
```

Exception:

```
1, 11
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1;3"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at javaproject1.Main.main(Main.java:22)
```

Comment: This error message does not have anything to do with regex...

Comment: What you're doing here is trying to parse `"1;3"` as a number. You are doing it in line `22` as the exception says. The line `22` is `Integer.parseInt(edge[i]);`

Comment: Yes, i want to delete special chars "; , . @" and get only numbers

Comment: Your regex is splitting only on white space, so 1;3 doesn't get split. '[\\s;]+' might get you past the semicolon. If you really want to split on anything but numbers, '[^\\d]+', I think

Comment: @zzxyz Thank you! :)

Comment: I corrected my code and now is ok :) Could you tell me how can i get size of Graph from numbers in file? I must calculate number of vertex from this file.

Comment: You'd probably want to post a new question.  Explain what the input means, show the expected output, and hopefully post something you're currently trying.  ps, for future regex issues, test your stuff here:  https://regex101.com/

Comment: Yes, exactly :) Thank you! I created new question about this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47605355/graph-dfs-algorithm-nullpointerexception

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is splitting only on white space, so 1;3 doesn't get split. '[\s;]+' might get you past the semicolon. If you really want to split on anything but numbers, '[^\d]+', … – zzxyz